# How can i automatically (silently) copy files off removable devices?

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I'm looking for a way to automatically have my computer copy all files (or specific files based on extension) from removable devices plugged in (USB sticks/HDDs/phones etc) to a designated folder on my computer.

This will be used as part of a penetration-test so it needs to be done silently/stealthily. I found [this script](http://edsalisbury.net/how-to-automatically-copy-images-from-removable-media/) for Linux but I haven't been able to find one for windows. Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you install software on your machine? If yes, take a look at this: http://bitstrickycorner.blogspot.com/2013/01/automatically-and-silently-copy-files.html